# Android progress bar setvisible not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, visibility

I have problem in seting visibility of Progressbar in a AsyncTask

this is my code:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView IV;
FullImageActivity MA;
ProgressBar lp1;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView IV,
        FullImageActivity fullImageActivity) {
    this.IV = IV;
    this.MA = fullImageActivity;
    lp1 = (ProgressBar) MA.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... p) {
    String url = "...";
    Bitmap BI = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
        BI = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return BI;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    lp1.setVisibility(1);
    super.onPreExecute();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    IV.setImageBitmap(result);
    lp1.setVisibility(0);
}
}
```

and my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i use

```
 lp1.setVisibility(0);
```

or

```
 lp1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
```

or

```
lp1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
lp1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

my progressBar still visible

Comment: Why you used progress bar used `Progress Dialog` instead  and dismiss it on `onPostExecute(.....)`

Comment: tanx @SimplePlan i use that

Answer (score 0):

```
 lp1.setVisibility(0);
```

`0` is the value for `View.VISIBILE`

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) the docs